# How to make SQLite view column to be of type REAL?

Tags: sqlite, view

Let us have the following sample code:

```
sqlite> create table t ( v1 real, v2 real );
sqlite> pragma table_info ( t );

0|v1|real|0||0
1|v2|real|0||0

sqlite> create view v as select v1, sum(v2) from t group by v1;
sqlite> pragma table_info ( v );

0|v1|real|0||0
1|sum(v2)||0||0
```

As seen above, the second column in the view has no type or affinity. My program needs the type of such column to be 'real'. Currently it reports that type as 'string' and stops working. Changing the program is out of my control, so I'm trying to set the type of the column in view to be 'real'.

Is there a solution for my problem?

I already tested the following without success:

```
create view vx as select v1, cast ( sum(v2) as real ) from t group by v1;
create view vy as select v1, sum(v2) * 1.0 from t group by v1;
```